# Handling halogen lamps

Tags: physical-chemistry, home-experiment

When consulting manuals, electricians, online sources, etc., they always instruct you to handle halogen light bulbs with gloves.

The "explanation" that usually accompanies this statement is that oils and salts from a bare hand can "react" with the surrounding glass/quartz, owing to the fact that halogen bulbs are much hotter than ordinary ones. These reactions would cause weak spots in the quartz (or in some versions of the story, the filament), decreasing the lifetime of the bulb.

Is there any merit to this explanation? What are then the precise mechanisms involved in the bulb's degradation when the bulb is touched by a dirty monkey finger?

Comment: It is most likely not a chemical reaction, quartz is quite inert even at higher temperatures but dirt and burned substances can cause thermal gradients and stress in the glass.

Comment: That seems plausible, although I'd love to see some numbers backing this up

Comment: I've never seen them say "react", generally, the explanation is that the extra oil will interfere with the cooling of the lamp, plus it'll burn etc (and might thus affect the lm output of the bulb).

Comment: I've even seen this warning printed on E27 ([A-series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-series_light_bulb)) halogen bulbs' boxes. Which is completely daft since the outer glass is not even of the quartz kind. At least [one FAQ](http://www.teklight.com/faq_s.html) mentions that MR16 (e.g. GU10) halogen bulbs don't need such precautions... which I assume apply to E27 halogen bulbs as well... because in these the filament is also double-shelled.

Comment: This question should be migrated to Engineering.SE

Comment: @CL22 This question is too old to migrate. If you think it is off-topic, please flag as "should be closed."

Comment: @rob For what it's worth, I think this fits perfectly fine on PhysicsSE; I asked about the physics, not the engineering of light bulbs

Comment: salt will react with hot glass, this is how "Gorilla Glass" is manufactured. The reaction with the salt is not a very energetic reaction because the atoms in both chemicals are very tightly bound it's more that the salt dissolves in the silica.

it seems entrely plausible to be that hot amorphous silica could take up environmental sodium chloride and by doing so gain different physical properties.

Answer (score 2):

The interesting point in halogen bulbs is that they managge to not, over time, cover the inside of the bulb glass with **condensed vapour** of the filament (1).
Therefore, the bulb can be **smaller**, as it's not needed to spread that metal over a large area.

Now, when touching the bulb, a **fingerprint** is left, which contains various **carbon compounds**. When switching on the bulb, it **carbonizes**, leaving slight dark residues (2).
Even if they are barely visible, they **cover a significant fraction** of the surface area, and make that area somewhat **less translucent**. That causes a reduction of light output over the livetime of the bulb,
adding up to a significant **loss in overall efficiency** of the halogen bulb.

---

*On the alternative explanations*:
The idea that somehow temperature differences are created, and cause a problem by weakening mechanical stability makes no sense - the kind of glass a halogen bulb is made of, quarz glas, is very stable under heat differences, as it changed it's volume only very little, compared to other glass.

(1) Instead, that vapour reacts with the halogen, to a compound that will subsequently split again into metal and halogen on the surface of the filament.

(2) I assume these carbon residues are long-lasting or permanent because the bulb surface is not hot enough to just burn them off.

Comment: So you're saying that it doesn't reduce the lifetime of the bulb, just reduce the net light output? And not by much too, because normally you'd only handle the bulb only *once*, to put it in...

Comment: Yes, that's what I expect. (The "once" is not relevant, though - it's the amount of fingerprint material when switching on that counts. Before that moment, wiping helps; after, it sticks to the glass pretty strong I think)

Answer (score 1):

Any oil from your fingers that resides on the outside of the halogen lamp will absorb some of the heat and light from the filament in operation, and cause the fingerprint area to be hotter than other parts of the bulb.

All it takes sometimes is a small differential in temperature for anything made of glass or quartz to develop a weak spot from the additional thermal / mechanical stress.

Wearing gloves or handling the bulb with something that won't leave fingerprints (I usually use a small piece of paper towel) is a very good idea.

Comment: How do you know this even helps? And for what bulbs?